# ! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float. when creating pseudocode algorithm in Latex

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

Here's my code :

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{algorithm} 

\caption{Calculate $A_{nxn}$} 
\label{Algorithm 1} 

\begin{algorithmic}
```

\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\end{enumerate}

```
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: A minimal working example would have helped...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to upload `algorithm`:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
 
See Algorithm \ref{algo-1}

\begin{algorithm} 
 \caption{Calculate $A_{nxn}$}\label{algo-1} 
 \begin{algorithmic}
  \IF{$n<0$} 
  \STATE $x \leftarrow X$ 
  \ENDIF 
 \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no, ! LaTeX Error: Command \algorithm already defined.

Comment: The MWE above works fine with no errors (TeX Live 2020). Are you running a different file?

Comment: No i run THE file and i get either this error : 
`! LaTeX Error: Command \RETURN already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` or `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside`

Comment: i am editing a `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`

Comment: Again, the code I provided above works correctly on TeX Live 2020 (also with `article` in place of `report`). If you get an error it may mean that 1) You don't have TeX Live 2020; 2) TeX Live is out of date; 3) You are using an online service such as Overleaf. Try deleting the auxiliary files. (The code works fine also in https://cocalc.com.)

Comment: No i have the last version of miktex and texworks installed on my PC

Comment: Also instead of your if else try enumerate See my EDIT pls

Comment: See this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348205/231952

Comment: You are not helping man sorry for your effort, but what worked is to  put begin enumerate right after begin algorithm and to remove algorithmc !! thanks anyway